# How to display all processor in graphical view?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

**Tool:** Spring Cloud Data Flow

I have created a sample with Source, Processor and Sink.
The graphical view of the whole app is

[image]

As I have an existing application which contains multiple Processor in a single project and enabled at once using code below

```
@EnableBinding({Processor.class, Processor1.class, Processor2.class})
```

Then, is there any possibility or configuration required so Data Flow can display all processor from the project?

It's really helpful if the Data Flow display processor with boundary and contains multiple processors in it (Shown in below image)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCDF Dashboard doesn't yet support this functionality.

Though it is possible to build multi-input/output based processors (in the same app) using Spring Cloud Stream, in SCDF today, primarily, the data pipelines are linear, with one-input/output representation.

We are exploring ideas to support this in SCDF proper. Please feel free to open a [new issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/issues) with your use-cases, and as much as details as possible of the requirements - we could use it for the acceptance.

Comment: Thanks Sabby for guide, let's see if we get this feature on SCDF.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/issues/1288